# How to retrieve this type of level of data from firebase

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase

**Hello All**

> Am new to firebase and ionic and i am creating chatting app that will
>   allow my app user to be able to chat directly with one another, i have
>   successfully been able to register user; fetch users and also been
>   able to message each user but my place of confusion is how am i going
>   to display the message

**Here is my Firebase Structure**

[Firebase Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSwD9.png)

**Here is my view code**

```
<ion-view view-title="Home Page">

<ion-content delegate-handle="show-page" >

    <!-- Loading Indicator -->
    <div class="loading"
         ng-if="data.loading" >
        <ion-spinner icon="ripple" ></ion-spinner >
        <p >Loading messages...</p >
    </div >

    <!-- Empty room message -->
    <div class="loading"
         ng-show="!data.loading && data.message.length == 0" >
        <p >This room is empty, be the first to post!</p >
    </div >

    <!-- Discussion list -->
    <div class="chat-messages">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="data in chatMessages">
                {{data.message}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</ion-content>

<ion-footer-bar keyboard-attach
                class="bar-assertive item-input-inset" >
    <label class="item-input-wrapper" >
        <input type="text"
               placeholder="Type your message"
               ng-enter="sendMessage()"
               ng-model="data.message" />
    </label >
    <button class="button button-clear"
            ng-click="sendMessage()" >
        Send
    </button >
</ion-footer-bar >
```

**And Here is my Controller**

```
app.controller('chatCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, $localStorage) {
    $scope.data = {
            messages: [],
            message: '',
            loading: true,
            showInfo: false
    };
    var to                      = $stateParams.UserName;
    $localStorage.from          = $stateParams.MyName;



    var roomName = 'chat_'+(to<$localStorage.from ? to+'_'+$localStorage.from : $localStorage.from+'_'+to);

    console.log(to+', '+$localStorage.from+' => '+ roomName);


    var messagesRef = new Firebase("https://bigzill.firebaseio.com/chatMessages/"+roomName);
    $scope.loadMessages = function () {
        $scope.data.messages    =$firebaseArray(messagesRef);
        $scope.data.messages.$loaded().then(function(data){
            console.log("Angular fire $loaded");
            $scope.data.loading =false;
            $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('show-page').scrollBottom(true);
        });
    };
    $scope.sendMessage = function(){
            var to               =   $stateParams.UserName;
            $localStorage.from   =   $stateParams.MyName;
            var from             =   $stateParams.MyName;
            var dataToDb         =  {from: from, to: to, message: $scope.data.message,timestamp: new Date().getTime()};
            var roomName = 'chat_'+(to<from ? to+'_'+from : from+'_'+to);
            var InsertChatRef = new Firebase('https://bigzill.firebaseio.com');
            var insertObj   =InsertChatRef.child('chatMessages').child(roomName);
            insertObj.push(dataToDb);

            $scope.data.message = '';

    };
});
```

Comment: okay this is what i have been able to get, i just went beneth my `$scope.loadMessages= function(){...} `and i added this code to it `$scope.loadMessages();` and when i reload my browser all i saw was the **This room is empty, be the first to post!** but believe me i have already added my message to it.... **please what am doing wrong**

Answer (score 0):

> wow...  coding involving see with a sharp sensitive eyes. i was able
>   to figure out the problem.

**the message is displaying now.**

> what i did was that my loadMessage() function was having
>   $scope.data.messages and in my view i was ng-repeating from a very
>   wrong $scope, so i change it to ng-repeat="data in data.messages" and
>   it worked